# Can Java Constructor construct an object of a subclass?

Tags: java, factory

Is there a way to modify the class being constructed in a constructor?

```
public class A {
  A() {
    //if (condition) return object of type B
    //else return A itself
  }
}
public class B extends A { }
```

Basically I want to use the base class constructor as a factory method. Is it possible in java?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, you'll have to use a factory method for `A` if you want to do this. The client of your class has a right to expect that, if they do `new A()`, they get an object of class `A`, and no other.

Comment: well, this is possible in some other languages. when user does new A() he can as well get subtype of A. So conceptually I see no issue.

Comment: Nonetheless, it is the expectation in Java.

Answer (score 5):

No, constructors will only to instantiate an object of the class they represent.  That is why there is no return value specified in the constructor.

Comment: Constructors don't return values

Answer (score 4):

You cannot do it in a constructor but you could do:

```
public class A {

private A(){ }

public static A getInstance(){
     if (condition) 
        return new B();
     else 
        return new A();
}

}

class B extends A {

}
```

Comment: thinking in possibilities

Answer (score 3):

When constructor code is being invoked the object is already created - you are only initializing its fields. So it's too late to modify class of the object.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using reflection to instantiate the subclass. However it is a bad idea because a class shouldn't know about its subclasses.

Using a factory method is the best approach in your case.